# Unique values two columns combobox vba

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, multiple-columns, unique-values

I need to display two columns A and B listed in a combobox with unique values. So if two rows have the same A but not the same B, it is not a duplicate, both column need to be duplicate. I found a code that list one column (A) with unique values but I don't know how to add the column B.

There's a picture of my data and how I want to display it in my ComboBox.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim Cell        As Range
    Dim col         As Variant
    Dim Descending  As Boolean
    Dim Entries     As Collection
    Dim Items       As Variant
    Dim index       As Long
    Dim j           As Long
    Dim RngBeg      As Range
    Dim RngEnd      As Range
    Dim row         As Long
    Dim Sorted      As Boolean
    Dim temp        As Variant
    Dim test        As Variant
    Dim Wks         As Worksheet

        Set Wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set RngBeg = Wks.Range("A3")
        col = RngBeg.Column

        Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp)

            Set Entries = New Collection
            ReDim Items(0)

            For row = RngBeg.row To RngEnd.row
                Set Cell = Wks.Cells(row, col)
                    On Error Resume Next
                        test = Entries(Cell.Text)
                        If Err = 5 Then
                            Entries.Add index, Cell.Text
                            Items(index) = Cell.Text
                            index = index + 1
                            ReDim Preserve Items(index)
                        End If
                    On Error GoTo 0
            Next row

        index = index - 1
        Descending = False
        ReDim Preserve Items(index)

            Do
                Sorted = True

                For j = 0 To index - 1
                    If Descending Xor StrComp(Items(j), Items(j + 1), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                        temp = Items(j + 1)
                        Items(j + 1) = Items(j)
                        Items(j) = temp

                        Sorted = False
                    End If
                Next j

                index = index - 1
            Loop Until Sorted Or index < 1

        ComboBox1.List = Items


End Sub
```

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Can you better explain what "both column need to be duplicate" means? Isn't if enough that val in column A to be different from B, on the same row?

Comment: I meant, is it necessary that **each column to contain only unique values**, besides condition to be different on the same row? If a filtering will be done before (to identify the unique values on each column, the correspondence between the values on the same row may be changed, I am afraid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please. It assumes that **`unique` definition means pairs of values from the two columns, on the same row, to be unique**:

```
Sub UnicTwoValInTwoColumns()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant, countD As Long
  Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, boolDupl As Boolean

  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
  'supposing that last row in column A:A is the same in column B:B
  'If not, the last row for B:B will be calculated and then the higher will be chosen:
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  ReDim arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To lastRow)    'redim the final array for maximum possible number of elements
  arr = sh.Range("A3:B" & lastRow).value 'pun in array the range to be analized
  k = 1 'initialize the first array element number

  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'iterate between the array elements
    boolDupl = False  'initialize the variable proving that the pair of data already in arrFin
    For j = 1 To k    'iterate between the arrFin elements in order to check for duplicates
        If arr(i, 1) & arr(i, 2) = arrFin(1, j) & arrFin(2, j) Then
              boolDupl = True: Exit For 'if a duplicate is found the loop is exited
        End If
    Next j
    If Not boolDupl Then 'load the arrFin only if a duplicate has not been found
        arrFin(1, k) = arr(i, 1): arrFin(2, k) = arr(i, 2)
        k = k + 1        'increment the (real) array number of elements
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(1 To 2, 1 To k - 1) 'redim array at the real dimension (preserving values)
  With Me.ComboBox1
      .ColumnCount = 2 'be sure that combo has 2 columns to receive values
      .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin) 'fill the combo with the array elements
  End With
End Sub
```

You can paste the code in the form Initialize event, or let the `Sub` like it is, copy it in the form module and only call it from the event in discussion. I would suggest you to proceed in this las way. If you have (or will have) something else in the event, it would be simpler to identify a problem if it occurs, I think,

Comment: Thanks for the help but he code you propose displays the two columns in the combobox but shows the duplicates.

Comment: @ I clearly asked you about it issue definition, but you did not say anything. Even now, you only say "shows duplicates". I also explained the assumption based on what the code works. So, what "duplicate" means in this very case? Can you explain based on what rule to avoid duplicates? If I will previously filter each column in order to have unique values, the correspondence between the two columns on the same row will be lost. I asked you clearly about this aspect, but you did not say anything... I have the impression you did not even read them...

Comment: @Lawrence231: If is difficult to explain your need in words, I would suggest you to edit your question an put a picture with your two columns like they are (something relevant) and another one showing us how do you want to look after processing. Not necessarily to be from combo box. In other two Excel columns it will be enough...

Comment: @ You are absolutely right I haven't seen your previous comments! Is it more clear if I say that I meant that If I have two rows with the same values in the column A and If these rows have the same values for the column B it means that they are duplicates?

Comment: @Lawrence231: Yes, after seeing your picture (too) your question became clear. I will adapt the answer code in order to make it solve your need.

Comment: @Lawrence231: Updated the code according to my (last) understanding. I commented the code lines in a way to easily make you understand what the code does. Please confirm that it work as you need and everything about it is clear enough. If not, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. But, please take care to be more focused on the issue... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and  your effort the code works great!!! :)

Comment: @Lawrence231:  Glad for being able to help!